# Creating chart using two ranges, both relative cells references

Tags: excel, charts, range, vba

I'm creating some vba code to create charts. I have the following code:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( (ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0)), (ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 2)))
```

I have a 3 column, 8 row area of cells. I will select cell A1 and then run the vba code. I want the vba code to select cells A4:A8 **and** C4:C8 (not B4:B8) and then create a chart from this.

The reason this needs to be relative is because I'll be moving the origination cell from which I run the vba code many times as I run the vba code multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes you could make to the code you've written.

First, the `ActiveChart` variable will be null if you've selected cell `A1`, as you will have a *cell*, not a *chart* selected. This can be addressed by selecting the chart in code.

Second, The `ActiveCell` variable will change as the cell changes. You will need to cache the value or update your offsets to match the offset from the previous cell in the range. I would recommend the former option.

Finally, it looks like the offsets are off by 1 from a starting point of A1.

I've made a few changes and the sub is shown below. Note that the name of the chart in this code is `MyChart`, but could easily be changed to whatever you have specified in your worksheet.

```
Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = ActiveCell

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyChart").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Range(cell.Offset(3, 0), cell.Offset(6, 0)), Range(cell.Offset(3, 2), cell.Offset(6, 2)))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version:

```
Sub ject()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ac As Range, ch As Chart
    Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set ac = ActiveCell
    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        .ChartObjects("newchart").Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Range(ac.Offset(3, 0).Resize(4).Address & "," & _
            ac.Offset(3, 2).Resize(4).Address).Select
        .Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnStacked, ac.Offset(0, 4).Left, _
            ac.Offset(0, 4).Top, 300, 250).Name = "newchart"
    End With
End Sub
```

This creates a *ColumnStacked Bar Chart* from the currently selected cell on the currently selected sheet.
 
The chart is placed on the 5th cell from the active cell. HTH.